# Custom Page Layout Default Focus

Tags: page-layout

How do you change the control that takes initial focus in edit mode for a custom page layout?

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server">
 <SharePointWebControls:TextField runat="server" FieldName="Title"  />
 <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField runat="server" FieldName="Content1" />
 <SharePointWebControls:NoteField runat="server" FieldName="Summary" />
 <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField runat="server" FieldName="Content2" />
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

In the example above I would like "Content2" to have initial focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do it for RichText Fields, and you do it via the `HasInitialFocus` property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.richhtmlfield.hasinitialfocus.aspx